# Error: cannot find module 'package.json' nexe

Tags: javascript, node.js

`nexe -i ./index.js -o Thumbnailer.bin -p /usr/bin/python2 --build`

After using nexe and trying to run my Binary i get the following Error Message:

```
╰─$ ./Thumbnailer.bin
        internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
        throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at f (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:33356:1092)
    at u (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:33356:1430)
    at c (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:33356:2750)
    at b.require (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:33356:3346)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:8401:26)
    at c (/home/lwolf/Projekte/Thumbnailer/Thumbnailer.bin:33356:3584)
```

in the index.js i do only require:
`const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');`

- Platform(OS/Version): Manajro 17
- Host Node Version: 10.4
- Target Node Version: 10.4
- Nexe version: 2.0.0-rc.30
- Python Version: 2

Comment: Well, do you and all your modules have the `package.json`? node usually does not lie to you, so I guess you don't have that package.json

Comment: @DanFromGermany i did a fresh `npm init` and `npm install` and i think that the packaga.json should be there but i will look after that.